# What is pointer Derefrencing in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I was learning about recursion using c and there was a question with an array say for example:

```
void main(){
     char str[100];
     --snip--
     if(*str == 'c')
        count++;
     --snip--
}
```

here *str is the value retrieved from the pointer that points to first character of the string **str**.

My question is what is pointer derefrencing and can i do as follows:

```
--snip--
str+=1;
--snip--
```

to get new pointer pointing to the next location of another character in that string?

Comment: This may help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s

Comment: *"can i do as follows"* - If you tried it, you would instantly notice that you cannot.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot increment an array, but you can increment a pointer to an element of the array:

```
char str[100];
char *pointer = str; //points to the begin
pointer++; //points to the second element
*pointer = 'a'; //sets the second element
```

`str` has the type `char [100]`, in some expressions it decays to (e.g. behaves like) a pointer, but it is not a pointer, you cannot assign to `str`. `str = ...` or `str+=1;` is invalid, you can only assign something to an element of an array, not the array itself.

Therefore you have to create a pointer to an element of the array and then you can increment the pointer.

Comment: is that not same as str+=1

Comment: str is a pointer

Comment: added some more text, is it better? An array is not a pointer

Comment: in the book it does str+1

Comment: what will str+1 do anyways?

Comment: `str+1` is different than `str+=1`. In `str+1` `str` decays to a pointer and then `1` gets added, so `str+1` points to the second element, but it does not change `str`.

Comment: now i understand it thanks!